# linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am stuck on this problem,have searched google a lot also..but could not get the appropriate solution for it.

Please help me to solve the error.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just do one thing. remove reference of  your .a file for that library and agin add it to your project.

Comment: sometimes re adding libs or restart of xcode works in these cases, just re configure the external libraries which you have added in your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello friend there are a lot of reason of linkers error. Some basic reason:
1. You can remove linker error goto Build Setting > Build Active Architecture Only set to No for Target and Project both.
2. Sometimes unnecessary .a files created Target>General. Delete irrelevant .a files from Build Setting>Search Paths.

Try this if still you got the error show me the screenshot.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The linker is missing the zbar library. You have either to put `libzbar.a` into a search path of the linker, or add the path to lib with `-L`.

Comment: I am a fresher and dont know how this can be achieved .Kindly guide a little more for it.

Comment: You can add library search paths (without `-L`) in the build settings.